# Role of maxPropagationDelay in link agent of UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

In the link agent, I came across attributes like `maxPropagationDelay` and `reservationGuardTime`. What is the role of these attributes? Where I can find more information about these attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are parameters of specific LINK protocols.

- `maxPropagationDelay` is used to determine timeouts based on expected round-trip-times in the network. It should be set to a value that depends on the geographical size of your network if the network is small enough for a single hop connection between any pair of nodes. Otherwise it should be set to a value based on the maximum communication range of your modem.
- `reservationGuardTime` is a small extra time that a channel is reserved for, to allow for practical timing jitter of modems. Usually the default value for this provided by the agent will be good enough for most purposes.

The *Underwater networks handbook* to be released with the upcoming version of UnetStack3 will provide a lot more guidance on many of these parameters, and on how to set up various types of networks using Unetstack.

Answer (score 1):

You can access more information about any **parameters** of any of the Agents in UnetStack using the `help` command. For the Link Agent, you'll see this in UnetStack 1.4.

```
> help link
link - access to link agent

Examples:
 link                           // access parameters
 link.maxRetries = 5            // set maximum retries for reliable delivery
 link << new DatagramReq(to: 2, data: [1,2,3], reliability: true)
                                // send reliable datagram

Parameters:
  MTU - maximum data transfer size
  maxRetries - maximum retries for reliable delivery
  reservationGuardTime - guard period (s)
  maxPropagationDelay - maximum propagation delay (s)
  dataChannel - channel to use for data frames (0 = control, 1 = data)
```

`reservationGuardTime` is the additional guard time that can be added to the frame duration when reserving a channel (using MAC) to ensure channel reservations have some delay in between for the nodes to be able react.

`maxPropagationDelay` is used to estimate the maximum time that an acknowledge to a request (or a series of requests if fragmentation is needed) might take and used to set timeouts for transmissions, or to make channel reservations (if using a MAC). Depending on your simulation/setup, you can change this number to be longest time (one-way) between two nodes which can communicate.